# symfony2 routing requirements combining 2 parameters

Tags: symfony, routes, requirements, symfony-2.3

So I got this in my routing.yml:

```
requirements:
    var1: \d+
    var2: \d+
```

Both are checked on their own and valid.
I need to check the combination of the 2, since the combination is not always valid.

For this case I need to check the relation between 2 objects in the database, the first should be the parent of the second.
I can do this in the controller, but I don't really like that implementation. Also, I need this same check for more than 1 route.

How would I add another requirement that checks the combination? Can I define a method in the controller class that would be called?

Or would the best solution be something like:

```
public function indexAction($var1, $var2)
{
    $result = $this->checkRelation($var1, $var2);
    if ($result) {
        // return errorpage
        return $result;
    }

    // ... 
}
```

Comment: I think you should add more informations : what type of combination is it? What sort of validation? (should show the controller's code that correspond to it for example)

Comment: You are right. Added info on database relation. But there might be other cases were "custom checks" might be needed where the routing-config doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution I went with was the following:

- add a method checkRelation that requires all parameters
- run a query inside that method to check if everything is ok.
- return false when there is a problem, return true when values are ok. (alternatively you can return an object or something)
- in the action I check if the value is false, if so I return a generic "not found" page for the specific controller.

In all this is very similar to what I posted in my initial question.

When using the same checkRelation in multiple controllers it might be a good idea to move it (partially) to a repository-class or something similar to prevent duplication of code/logic.

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand your question, you want the following:

```
/parent/child/        --> returns 200
/not_parent/not_child --> returns 404
```

The Symfony2 Routing component doesn't do this natively, but you could extend it.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/cookbook/using-a-custom-route-repository.html

Comment: I can find in the documentation how to create a custom validator, however, I cannot find how to use this in routing.yml. The documentation appears to state it to be only for validating entity's, not route's.

Comment: Sorry, I obviously didn't read your question properly. Editing now.

Comment: Yup, that is what I'm looking for. Suggested solution does seem a bit overkill. I might be better of in keeping the check in the controller. I do know that when the combination is invalid, there will not be another route that does match.